# jQuery Slide Show not centering

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, asp.net

I have a slide show that I've created out of HTML/asp.net, jQuery and CSS. I have everything working perfectly fine but I would like to center it on my web page. No matter what I do, I get a weird result.

Anytime I try and do `margin-left: auto` and `margin-right: auto` nothing happens. It stays to the left of the page. When I try and do a `text-align: center` I do not see any change either.

Below is all my code:

HTML/asp.net:

```
<%@ Page Title="Home Page" Language="C#" MasterPageFile="~/Site.master" AutoEventWireup="true"
CodeBehind="Default.aspx.cs" Inherits="mypage._Default" %>

<asp:Content ID="HeaderContent" runat="server" ContentPlaceHolderID="HeadContent">
<link href="/Styles/Home.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
</asp:Content>
<asp:Content ID="BodyContent" runat="server" ContentPlaceHolderID="MainContent">

<div id="slideshow">
<img src="Images/me.jpg" alt="" class="active" height="500" width="700"/>
<img src="Images/WaterfallPic.JPG" alt="" height="500" width="700"/>
</div>
<script type="text/javascript" src="Scripts/jquery-1.4.1.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="Scripts/HomeSlideshow.js">
slideSwitch();
</script>
</asp:Content>
```

JavaScript:

```
function slideSwitch() {
var $active = $('#slideshow IMG.active');

if ($active.length == 0) $active = $('#slideshow IMG:last');

var $next = $active.next().length ? $active.next()
    : $('#slideshow IMG:first');

$active.addClass('last-active');

$next.css({ opacity: 0.0 })
    .addClass('active')
    .animate({ opacity: 1.0 }, 1000, function () {
        $active.removeClass('active last-active');
    });
}

$(function () {
setInterval("slideSwitch()", 5000);
});
```

CSS:

```
#slideshow {
position:relative;
height:350px;
width: 350px;
text-align: center;

}
#slideshow IMG {
position:absolute;
top:0;
left:3px;
z-index:8;
float: none;
}

#slideshow IMG.active {
z-index:10;
}

#slideshow IMG.last-active {
z-index:9;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In the css, #slideshow is positioned relatively.  In this case, it's relative to the top left.  Margins arent going to affect it.

Either take out the relative positioning or add "position:static" to the css on the div element

```
<div id="slideshow" style='position:static'>
```

Comment: When I do that, it moves even further up into the upper left hand corner and even overlaps the master page.

Comment: Now add the margins back in

Comment: What's also weird is that if I do leave it as `position: relative` and set my margins to auto, it moves to the right hand side of the web page (with about 200px of padding). So it's off center to the right...